How to divide text and element node of a certain element into two parts without loosing markup in xslt transfromation from html to xml?
I have the following html markup.
<p>
  <i>This is italic tag</i>. This text belongs to x element. The text from here should <sub>2</sub>   belong to y element.
</p>

And here is the template rule I am using:
`<xsl:template match="p/text()[not(parent::i)]">
    <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(.,'\.')"/>
    <xsl:element name="x">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($tokens[2])"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="y">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(string-join($tokens[position() > 2 and position() != last()], '.'))"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>`

`<xsl:template match="sub">
    <xsl:element name="SUBSCRIPT">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>`

`<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:element name="PARA">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>`

`<xsl:template match="i">
    <xsl:element name="EMPHASIS">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>`


When running the transformation some text is missing in the output.
This is what I am getting now:
`<PARA>
    <EMPHASIS>This is italic tag</EMPHASIS>
    <X>This text belongs to x element</X>
    <Y/>
    <SUBSCRIPT>2</SUBSCRIPT>
    <X/>
    <Y/>
</PARA>`

What I am expecting:
`<PARA>
     <EMPHASIS>This is italic tag</EMPHASIS>
     <X>This text belongs to x element</X>
     <Y>The text from here should <SUBSCRIPT>2</SUBSCRIPT> belong to y element</Y>      
</PARA>`

How can I make sure that when dividing the p tag's text node and its element node (child element node except for i child) there is no content loss and sub element is also transformed correctly?

One approach is to convert the dot to an element (e.g. <dot/>) or a processing-instruction (e.g. <?dot?>) in a first processing step and then use for-each-group group-starting-with/group-ending-with in a second processing step to identify your nodes you want to wrap and inside the for-each-group to do the wrapping and process the grouped nodes.

Here is how you could tackle it:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:mode name="markers" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:mode name="analyze"/>

  <xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:variable name="markers" as="element(p)">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="markers"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$markers" mode="wrap"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template mode="markers" match="p//text()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string(., '\.')" mode="analyze"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template mode="analyze" match="*:match">
    <dot/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template mode="wrap" match="p">
    <PARA>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-ending-with="dot">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="position() = 2">
            <x>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </x>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="position() = 3">
            <y>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </y>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </PARA>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="dot"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="i">
    <EMPHASIS>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </EMPHASIS>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="sub">
    <SUBSCRIPT>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </SUBSCRIPT>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:comment>Run with {system-property('xsl:product-name')} {system-property('xsl:product-version')} at {current-dateTime()}</xsl:comment>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Online fiddle.
